# DotCMS or Tinymce: Remove the "Edit Image" option in a Binary field

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins, dotcms

We have a binary field that accepts only images (accept=image/*)?
Is there a way to remove the "Edit Image" option?
Note: I can also use tinymce.
Thanks a lot!

[image]